# Semantics of gwt's requestfactory's RequestContext.edit()

Tags: gwt, edit, requestfactory, requestcontext

I wonder if I am right about the semantics of the method RequestContext.edit() (GWT 2.5.1).
In my opinion, the alert in the following snippet should never happen. Am I right or just wrong about the semantics of RequestContext.edit()?

```
        ICurTournamentPu ctpu = c.getPu(PUK3.curTournament);
        TourneyProxy origTourney = ctpu.getTourney();
        this.tourney = req.edit(origTourney);

        // TODO begin test
        {
            List<DisciplineProxy> otdl = origTourney.getTourneyDisciplines().getList();
            List<DisciplineProxy> tdl = tourney.getTourneyDisciplines().getList(); 
            if (otdl != null && tdl != null && otdl.size() != tdl.size()) {
                Window.alert("otdl.size()=" + otdl.size() + " != " + tdl.size() + "=tdl.size()");
            }
        }
        // TODO end test
```

It appears that a list that is referenced through some links from the editable entity contains more elements than the list that is referenced through the equivalent links from the original non-editable entity. And this happens immediately after the call to RequestContext.edit(). It seems that in some way, old changes from the same client have been preserved even after a refresh from the server.
By the way, what would be the defined semantics of the following scenario:

1. client 1: load an entity e with version 1 and keep it in variable e1
2. client 2: change and persist e
3. client 1: load entity e again (with version 2) and keep it in variable e2
4. client 1: create a RequestContext "req"
5. client 1: editableE1 = req.edit(e1);
6. client 1: editableE2 = req.edit(e2);

What is the defined value of editableE2, then? Same object as editableE1 because already edited in this context? Or a new AutoBean? A little confusing... Can anybody clarify for me? :)

Comment: Meanwhile, I have found out, that there is some sort of caching in a request context and that my alert only happens when RequestContext.edit() has returned a cached instance. But, this still leaves the question about the actual semantics of RequestContext.edit()...

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for troubles!

`editableE2` would be the same as `editableE1`, i.e. an editable bean whose *parent* immutable bean is `e1`.